# Filtering with DjangoRestMultipleModels

Tags: django-rest-framework

According to [the relevant documentation](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering.html#django-rest-framework-filters) "Django Rest Frameworks default Filter Backends work out of the box" with DjangoRestMultipleModels. So, I'd expect the following code to work:

```
class AllModelSummary(MultipleModelAPIView):
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend,)
    search_fields = ('name','description',)
    #filter_fields = ('is_foo','is_bar',) # Everything breaks when this is uncommmented
    flat = True

    def get_queryList(self):
        queryList = (
            (Foo.objects.all(), FooSerializerMiniList),
            (Bar.objects.all(), BarSerializerMiniList)
        )

        return queryList

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here's an example of one of those serializers:

```
class BarSerializerMiniList(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_bar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_is_foo(self,obj):
        return False

    def get_is_bar(self,obj):
        return True

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('pk','name','description','is_bar','is_foo')
```

The search fields do exactly what they're supposed to do, but if I define `filter_fields` in the API then I am greeted by this:

```
'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: is_foo, is_bar
```

Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong here would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to work around the issue as follows:

```
class AllModelSummary(MultipleModelAPIView):
    ...
    def get_querylist(self):
        types = self.request.query_params['types']
        queryList = ()
        if types:
            for t in types.split(','):
                if t == 'foo':
                    queryList = queryList + ((Foo.objects.all(), FooSerializerMiniList),)
                elif t == 'bar':
                    queryList = queryList + ((Bar.objects.all(), BarSerializerMiniList),)
        else:
            queryList = (
                (Foo.objects.all(), FooSerializerMiniList),
                (Bar.objects.all(), BarSerializerMiniList),
            )

        return queryList
```

Then, appending `?types=foo,bar` to the URL does the trick.